# (A simple way) to make calling a function with a certain value is a compile-time error?

Tags: haskell

I think it's not possible (or requires certain language extensions) to make a function like

```
f :: Maybe Int
f (Just n) = n
f Nothing = ... -- a compile-time error
```

There's also no way you can make a function like:

```
g :: MyClass a => Int -> a
g n | n < 10    = TypeClassInstance
    | otherwise = OtherTypeClassInstance
```

So, I'm working on this tic-tac-toe API from the famous [NICTA FP course](https://github.com/NICTA/course) that [is required to do things like](https://github.com/NICTA/course/blob/master/projects/TicTacToe/TicTacToe.markdown):

> takeBack: takes either a finished board or a board in-play that has had at least one move and returns a board in-play. It is a compile-time type error to call this function on an empty board.

I think it's possible to do some really fancy type-level programming. But even if it is then I don't think someone who has just taken a 2-day introduction to functional programming could know it. Or did I miss something?

### Update

Based the example given by @user2407038 and clarification from @Cirdec, I write this and it does make a compile-time error when you try to `takeBack` on an empty board which is great.

However -- moving the goal posts a little -- this trick seems limited. There's another requirement that you can't move on a game that's already over.

> move: takes a tic-tac-toe board and position and moves to that position (if not occupied) returning a new board. This function can only be called on a board that is empty or in-play. Calling move on a game board that is finished is a compile-time type error.

It doesn't seem like a simple trick of having the type count the moves can be used in the case of complicated logic to determine whether the game is over.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data N = S N | Z

data Stat
  = Empty
  | InPlay
  | Won
  deriving Show

data Board (n :: N)
  = Board Stat [Int]
  deriving Show

newBoard :: Board Z
newBoard = Board Empty []

move :: Int -> Board a -> Board (S a)
move x (Board Empty []) = Board InPlay [x]
move x (Board InPlay xs) = Board Won (x:xs)

takeBack :: Board (S a) -> Board a
takeBack (Board InPlay [x]) = Board Empty []
takeBack (Board InPlay (x:xs)) = Board InPlay xs
takeBack (Board Won (x:xs)) = Board InPlay xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
    brd = newBoard    -- Empty
    m1 = move 1 brd   -- InPlay
    m2 = move 2 m1    -- Won
    m3 = move 3 m2    -- Can't make this a compile-time error with this trick
    tb2 = takeBack m2 -- Won
    tb1 = takeBack tb2 -- InPlay
    tb0 = takeBack tb1 -- Empty -> Compile-time error Yay!
  return ()
```

Comment: Regarding your update and `move`, is the goal of the exercise to play type-level tic-tac-toe? Have you considered that "finished" and "in-play", which aren't defined in the exercises, might mean something other than "has three in a row on the board or the board is full" and "is non-empty and isn't finished"?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like your first example with a GADT (generalized algebraic datatype);

```
data SMaybe (a :: Maybe *) where 
  SJust :: a -> SMaybe (Just a)
  SNothing :: SMaybe Nothing 

f :: SMaybe (Just a) -> a 
f (SJust a) = a 
-- f SNothing = undefined -- Including this case is a compile time error
```

Although I doubt this has much use. The simplest solution to the board thing is probably have a phantom type parameter on your `Board` datatype:

```
type Empty = False
type NonEmpty = True
data Board (b :: Bool) = Board ...

newBoard :: Board Empty
newBoard = Board ...

setAt :: (Int, Int) -> Bool -> Board a -> Board NonEmpty 
setAt p b (Board ...) = ...

takeBack :: Board NonEmpty -> Board NonEmpty
takeBack (Board ...) = ...
```

You can increase the amount of information stored on the type level if you like. For example, you can have the number of filled "cells":

```
data N = S N | Z -- The naturals

data Board (n :: N) = Board ...

newBoard :: Board Z
newBoard = Board ...

setAt :: (Int, Int) -> Bool -> Board a -> Board (S a)
setAt = ...

takeBack :: Board (S n) -> Board (S n)
takeBack = ...
```

The examples above use DataKinds for convenience, but it isn't needed.

Comment: `takeBack` should have the type `Board (S n) -> Board n`, since it is removing one move from the board.

Comment: Thanks. The phantom-type seems promising until I try it and realize that `takeBack` can yield a `Board Empty` or a `Board NonEmpty` depending on if there has been 1 or more moves before. So there's still the same problem of the type changing based on the input value.

Comment: @Cirdec That works perfectly for `takeBack` but see my update for why it's still too limited.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to accomplish something like this without invoking any type-level programming is a [smart constructor](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors). To make a smart constructor, you don't export the real constructor for a data type and instead provide a function that only creates values of the type that meet your other rules.

We can tackle the example problem by making smart constructors that represent a proof that a board is `Playable`, `Finished`, or `NonEmpty`.

```
type Position = (Int, Int)
type Player = Bool

data Board = Board -- ...
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)

newtype Playable = Playable {getPlayable :: Board}
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype Finished = Finished {getFinished :: Board}
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype NonEmpty = NonEmpty {getNonEmpty :: Board}
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

We are careful not to provide instances that could create any of these types; for example, we didn't derive `Read` instances for them. The only exported functions that will create these will first check the necessary conditions.

```
playable :: Board -> Maybe Playable
playable = undefined

finished :: Board -> Maybe Finished
finished = undefined

nonEmpty :: Board -> Maybe NonEmpty
nonEmpty = undefined
```

When we export the types from the module, we won't export their constructors

```
module TicTacToe (    
    Playable (getPlayable),
    Finished (getFinished),
    NonEmpty (getNonEmpty),

    playable,
    finished,
    nonEmpty,

    Position,
    Player,

    Board (..),
    move,
    whoWon,
    takeBack,
    playerAt
) where
```

The remaining functions can require that the client code has already gotten a type-level proof of the necessary property before invoking the function.

```
move :: Position -> Playable -> Board
move = undefined

whoWon :: Finished -> Player
whoWon = undefined

takeBack :: NonEmpty -> Board
takeBack = undefined
```

For this example problem, the smart constructors accomplished absolutely nothing. Any library user is going to define helper functions so that they only have to concern themselves with `Maybe` and not with any of these other special Board types.

```
move' :: Position -> Board -> Maybe Board
move' p = fmap (move p) . playable

whoWon' :: Board -> Maybe Player
whoWon' = fmap whoWon . finished

takeBack' :: Board -> Maybe Board
takeBack' = fmap takeBack . nonEmpty
```

This suggests that using `Maybe` in the interface is sufficient, and the requirements for compile-time errors in the exercise are superfluous. This also falls in line with the following requested function, which doesn't require a type-level proof that someone has moved in that position before being used.

```
playerAt :: Position -> Board -> Maybe Player
playerAt = undefined
```

Using type-level proofs of properties is more advantageous when there are many transformations for which those properties are invariant or can be easily deduced.